# Error on Java libgdx with AssetsManager

Tags: java, libgdx, assets

So I start to try to do some game in java with libgdx, and I am trying to use the AssetsManager. but it keeps giving an error. I will put the code (**I will try to resume the code**) and the output.
The game goes through the loading screen fine but when it reaches the game screen it stops and gives an error, I do believe it's because the assets.
If someone knows why I am getting this error.

**DesktopLauncher.java**

```
public class DesktopLauncher {
    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        new LwjglApplication(new pressme(), config);
    }
}
```

---

**pressme.java**

```
public class pressme extends Game {

    LoadingScreen loadingscreen;
    AssetsManager assetsmanager;
    Assets assets;


    @Override
    public void create() {
        assets = new Assets();
        assetsmanager = new AssetsManager();
        assetsmanager.load();
        assets.other();
        loadingscreen = new LoadingScreen(this);
        setScreen(loadingscreen);       
    }
}
```

---

**LoadingScreen.java**

```
public class LoadingScreen implements Screen {

    Assets assets;
    AssetsManager assetsmanager;
    private final pressme game;
    public GameScreen game_screen;

    public LoadingScreen(final pressme game){

        assets = new Assets();
        assetsmanager = new AssetsManager();
        this.game = game;

    }
    @Override
    public void show() {
        assetsmanager.load();

    }

    private void update(float delta){

        System.out.println(progress);
        if(assetsmanager.manager.update()) {
            game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game));
          }
        progress = assetsmanager.manager.getProgress();     
    }

}
```

---

**GameScreen.java**

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {
    pressme game;
    Assets assets;
    AssetsManager assetsmanager;

    public GameScreen(pressme game){
        this.game = game;
        assets = new Assets();
        assetsmanager = new AssetsManager();
    }
    @Override
    public void render(float delta) { 

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor( 0.5F, 0.5F, 0.5F, 0.5F);
        Gdx.gl.glClear( GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );


        camera.update();
        generalUpdate(touch, camera);

        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        assets.load();
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(assets.back, 0, 0);
        batch.end();
   }


 }
```

---

**Assets.java**

```
public class Assets {

    AssetsManager assetsmanager;

    public Sprite back;

    public void load(){
        assetsmanager = new AssetsManager();
        assetsmanager.load();
        back = new Sprite(assetsmanager.manager.get(assetsmanager.back, Texture.class));
    }
}
```

---

**AssetsManager.java**

```
public class AssetsManager {

    public AssetManager manager = new AssetManager();

    public String back  = "back.png";

    public void load(){

    manager.load(back, Texture.class);

    }
}
```

---

**Output**

```
LOADINGGG
0.0 

0.0 

0.015151516 

0.015151516 

0.030303031 

    .
    .
    .
0.969697 

0.9848485 

0.9848485 

Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException

     at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch.draw(SpriteBatch.java:586)

     at com.david.pressme.GameScreen.render(GameScreen.java:244)

     at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)

     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:223)

     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:124)
```

---

**EDIT**

> RC Thank you for the tip

So After I put the "***assets.load()***" still with some error. I dont know if the "***assets.load()***" it is on the right place

```
LOADINGGG
0.0
0.0
0.015151516
0.015151516
0.030303031
.
.
.
0.969697
0.969697
0.9848485
0.9848485
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Asset not loaded: back.png
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.get(AssetManager.java:144)
    at com.david.pressme.Assets.load(Assets.java:254)
    at com.david.pressme.GameScreen.render(GameScreen.java:172)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:223)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:124)
```

**EDIT2**

RC, Spylot ty for the tips, it was what you said

So its resolved, i puting

```
"assets.load" on "public void show()"
```

this way when the screen its load he loads the assest on the begin, and i take it off from the

```
"public void render(){"
```

because he was always loading the assests because its a loop (I think so), then on

```
"Assets.java public load(){" i put "assetsmanager.load();"
```

Thanks Rc for the tips. Then on the same place I put the

```
"assetsmanager.manager.finishLoading();"
```

so it loads all assets before do something. Thank you spylot for the tip.

Thank you all who help or try to help much appreciate.

Comment: The issue is most likely because `Assets#back` is null (because `Assets#load()` is never called), and a null is hard to draw

Comment: so a add the "assets.load" before "batch.begin();" (I dont know if its the right place to put it), but gives me a error i will edit the post

Comment: Yeah because it's obviously the same for AssetManager (load not called), Maybe you should take the time to read the doc and some tutorial.

Comment: I guess problem is with the path name. add folder name also in the path, like "data/back.png"

Comment: @RC, well i thought that when i call "assets.load()" it would call "assetsmanager.load()" too, because on assets.load there is one assestmanager.load()   ->                             **`public void load(){
  
  assetsmanager = new AssetsManager();
  assetsmanager.load();`**

Comment: @Kumar it could be but i dont think so, I will check, but I think that he uses internal path, he dont needs "assets/back.png", only "back.png".

Comment: @RC thaks for your help, its resolved and srry for my bad code :D, i will post what i did, it was what you said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be aware that when you're loading assets, you cannot use them until you call finishLoading. finishLoading blocks all calls trying to grab onto the asset until they are fully loaded in the memory.

I highly suggest you to read the [AssetManager API](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/assets/AssetManager.html).

So in short, after each time you use load() call, you should finish it off using `manager.finishLoading()`

Comment: Although it seems to be good answer you should describe shortly what is the problem and what `finishLoading` do

Comment: @m.antkowicz I hope it's satisfactory now. :)

Comment: but if i use "finishLoading", I think the LoadingScreen will not work, because only it will appear after all assets are loaded. and the purpose of loadingscreen it is appear when the assets are being loaded and show the process

Comment: @David Borges the fact is, you can't access the assets you're loading until you use finishLoading. You gotta work around that by 1) using update(); that once it returns true, you switch state (but this might be lightening quick) 2) you create a loading screen independent of the AssetManager (aka you initiate it as public static somewhere else) and set a Timer that after few seconds, fires off your update() or switches state.

Comment: @Spylot On LoadingScreen.java i am using this  "** if(assetsmanager.manager.update()) {     
            game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game));   
          }  **", it is not what are you saying?

Comment: @DavidBorges Yeah. Exactly. I wanted to mention it in my earlier  comment but decided not. It's just gonna be lightening fast though I guess on PC. Have you tried adding `manager.finishLoading()` after the last `manager.load()`?

Comment: @spylot Its solved thak you alot i will edit the post with what i did, it was after all what you said

Comment: @DavidBorges I'd appreciate it if you accept my answer then, thanks! :)